# Put space between body and footer

Tags: html, css

I'm new here, apologies if something is wrong.

So I'm really new to HMTL/CSS, I've learned a lot so far. Right now I'm having trouble getting a good amount of space (~30-40px) between the content of my site and my new footer. I've tried adding a `margin-top` as well as a `padding-top`, but they don't seem to have an effect. My footer is made by div class footer.

[My jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fv7sr952)

I'm using Google Chrome and writing on Sublime Text.

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example._"

Comment: @csm_dev isn't a working fiddle enough?

Comment: As per the flagging options, which I quoted above, no. Fiddle is good but the code must be in the question itself - links break.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to clear the float in the middle container.

```
#homeboxes:after {
    clear: both;
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
```

add that code to your CSS and you'll be able to increase the margin-top on your #footer div.

I would recommend to read this: https://alistapart.com/article/css-floats-101 as if you understand positioning in CSS you will be able to do almost anything with it. it is a very powerful tool but if you don't understand it, it can be very frustrating.

Comment: Wow that works great, thanks! So if you don't mind, what exactly does this do and how does it work? So I know for the future.

Comment: that is quite a task to answer your follow up question, if you read the blogpost I linked I think you'll understand why and what the clearing of the float do. it can't be answered in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.footer` class, in the `CSS` file, add the `display: inline-block;` and remove the `padding` property.

```
.footer {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 2%;
}
```

`margin-top: 2%;` is just an example, put any value you want.